# Melt the ice in rain drain

Tags: rain

What sort of heating cable can be installed in the downspout and subsequent drain drain ?
I was thinking of about 100 feet of drain that will be underground.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a drain that actually drains you shouldn't ever need to heat it or melt anything. Well, unless you live in the Arctic or Antarctica. But, even in those places it's just a matter of getting the pipe under the frost line to be totally sure there's never a problem. Any kind of hot-wire would need to be replaced often & therefore would never be worth shorting the frost line.